# R - Dynamically iterate per group over one column for differences > 26.5 and timestamp less than < 48

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration

I am trying to write a script in R studio with the intention to capture IF a patient develops Acute Kidney Injury and if so, THE FIRST TIMEPOINT this happens. Acute Kidney Injury is defined as follows below:

Increase in Creatinine (the name of the lab test) >= 26.5 umol/litre (the unit) within 48 hours

Please see an example table below how the data structure looks like:

```
PatientKey             Creatinine            Timestamp                 Mycommentsforthisquestion
1                      70                    2020-04-03 14:10:10
1                      90                    2020-04-03 17:11:10
1                      98                    2020-04-03 19:10:10       FIRST TIME OF AKI, i.e. > 26.5 
                                                                       increase and less than 48 hours
1                      100                   2020-04-03 22:10:10       NOT RELEVANT, AKI ALREADY

2                      140                   2019-08-01 00:00:00       ONLY ONE VALUE, IGNORE SINCE NO 
                                                                       DIFFERENCE CAN BE CALCULATED

3                      120                   2017-01-06 00:00:05       CAME TO HOSPITAL WITH HIGH VALUE
3                      70                    2017-01-06 10:00:05       DECREASES MORE THAN 26.5 DONT 
                                                                       COUNT --> NO AKI                 
3                      80                    2017-01-08 10:00:05

4                      70                    2020-01-08 22:00:05
4                      60                    2020-01-09 22:00:05       NOTE IT IS NOT ALWAYS THE FIRST 
                                                                       TEST THAT SERVES AS THE COMPARISON 
                                                                       VALUE
4                      90                    2020-01-10 02:00:05       90 - 60 > 26.5 --> AKI
4                      110                   2020-01-10 06:00:05       NOT RELEVANT, AKI ALREADY 

5                      50                    2020-01-12 06:00:05
5                      70                    2020-01-13 08:00:05 
5                      80                    2020-01-14 22:00:05       NO AKI, DIFFERENCE > 26.5 BUT MORE 
                                                                       THAN 48 HOURS BETWEEN TESTS
```

The desired output I want from this is something like below:

```
PatientKey    CreatinineLOW    CreatinineHIGH   TimestampLOW          TimestampHIGH 
1             70               98               2020-04-03 14:10:10   2020-04-03 19:10:10
4             60               90               2020-01-09 22:00:05   2020-01-10 02:00:05
```

Please note that only patient 1 developped AKI and thus only the data for that patient should be included in the output.

Is this something that is feasible to get done in R? I tried to use the dplyr/tidyverse package and do something like (MYDATA is the name of the dataframe):

```
datalist = list()

for (m in MYDATA$PatientKey %>% unique()) {
  x = filter(MYDATA, PatientKey == m) %>% pull(PatientKey)
  table <- MYDATA %>% filter(PatientKey == m) %>% arrange(Timestamp)
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
     table %>% 
     mutate(indx_creat = Creatinine[1],
     new_creatinine = Creatinine - indx_creat,
     indx_time = Timestamp[i],
     new_time = as.numeric(difftime(Timestamp, indx_time, units = "hours"))) %>%
  filter(new_creatinine >= 26.5 & new_time <= -48) -> r
 if (nrow(r) == 0) {
   table <- table[-1,]
 } else if (nrow(r) > 0 {
   datalist[[i]] <- r
   break
  }
 }
}

summary.table = do.call(rbind, datalist)
summary.table <- summary_table %>% group_by(PatientKey) %>% slice(1)
```

However, this did not work! Anyone has some idea about how to get the job done? It would be of great use for the clinical community to use programming to easily detect Acute Kidney Injury!

Comment: How would you like to define "baseline" Cr? Minimum Cr? Also, should Patientkey 4 also be included in output as also having AKI?

Comment: Actually the baseline part is easy to deal with, so only the question about the > 26.5 increase that is of importance, will remove the other part from the question. You are perfectly right about patient 4 as well, will also edit this in the question, thanks!

Comment: It would be far easier if it was possible to create an AKI variable ahead of time, rather than trying to create a tool that would parse through text to determine whether the particular case is relevant or not.

Comment: Phil I am not sure I understand what you are referring to, sorry about that, but the problem is that we do not know a priori which patients developped AKI as well as which lab value should serve as the comparison value (i.e. could be the patients first, second, third, fourth etc creatinine value that is the comparison for subsequent elevated creatinine values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do this in two steps to make it a bit more generically applicable.

**Step 1: find *any* critical increase per observation**
First, we'll create a column of nested dataframes, each containing *any* row that shows a critical increase of Creatinin:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

# loading OPs data
df <- structure(list(PatientKey = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Creatinine = c(70L, 90L, 98L, 100L, 
140L, 120L, 70L, 80L, 70L, 60L, 90L, 110L, 50L, 70L, 80L), Timestamp = c("2020-04-03 14:10:10", 
"2020-04-03 17:11:10", "2020-04-03 19:10:10", "2020-04-03 22:10:10", 
"2019-08-01 00:00:00", "2017-01-06 00:00:05", "2017-01-06 10:00:05", 
"2017-01-08 10:00:05", "2020-01-08 22:00:05", "2020-01-09 22:00:05", 
"2020-01-10 02:00:05", "2020-01-10 06:00:05", "2020-01-12 06:00:05", 
"2020-01-13 08:00:05", "2020-01-14 22:00:05")), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")

# find any critical increase, per observation row
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    Timestamp = as_datetime(Timestamp)
  ) %>%
  group_by(PatientKey) %>%
  do(
    mutate(.,
      critical_increase = map2(
        Creatinine, Timestamp,
        .f = function(c, t, data) {
          data %>%
            filter(
              Creatinine - c >= 26.5,
              Timestamp > t,
              as.numeric(Timestamp - t, units = "hours") <= 48
            ) %>%
            select(Timestamp, Creatinine)
        },
        data = .
      )
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The above code maps over the "Creatinine" and "Timestamp" of each row and throws in the grouped subset of the respective patient's data as well to filter it for critical increases. That filtered df is stored in the column "critical_increase".

**Step 2: bring data into expected format**
Now, to arrive at the format you described, we'll unnest the dataframes that we have calculated before, rename the columns to what you want them to be and pick the first row per patient, by "TimestampHIGH":

```
# unnest, rename & select first critical increase
df_final <- df2 %>%
  unnest(critical_increase, names_sep = ".") %>%
  transmute(
    PatientKey = PatientKey,
    CreatinineLOW = Creatinine,
    CreatinineHIGH = critical_increase.Creatinine,
    TimestampLOW = Timestamp,
    TimestampHIGH = critical_increase.Timestamp
  ) %>%
  group_by(PatientKey) %>%
  arrange(TimestampHIGH, desc(TimestampLOW)) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

You could easily do variations, like `arrange(desc(CreatinineHIGH - CreatinineLOW))` to find the maximal observed increase within 48h.

**Result**
The above gives you the expected result:

```
> df_final
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  PatientKey CreatinineLOW CreatinineHIGH TimestampLOW        TimestampHIGH      
       <int>         <int>          <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1          4            60             90 2020-01-09 22:00:05 2020-01-10 02:00:05
2          1            70             98 2020-04-03 14:10:10 2020-04-03 19:10:10
```

Comment: This works like a charm, very useful for detecting Acute Kidney Injury in clinical data, thanks!!